# Synchronize data between front end and database

Tags: reactjs, oracle, electron

I am having a requirement where I will fetch a table from DB and then show it as a tabular format in the front-end side. The user can edit the data, add a row, or delete a row. After everything is finished he will click save.

Now I need to synchronize the changes he has made with the table in the database i.e I want the modifications he has made to be reflected in the DB.

-> One thing I can do is truncate the table in the database and do a row by row insert, but this will be a problem cause there is a chance of data loss.

-> I can keep track of all the changes he has made and update those changes one by one, but this will be very complex to implement. (at least for me)

One more question, for the following requirement, could you suggest me between using electronjs and reactjs cause both satisfy my requirement, But I am not at all familiar with electronjs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, hence adding this as an answer. If the question is which of the two approaches should you go for, then definitely the second one.

The data-model/the table in the database should ideally have unique identifiers (primary keys) that uniquely identify each row in a table/entity. You would use this to perform update operations only on the affected rows.

What you are looking to do is what is one part of what is referred to as CRUD operations. CRUD stands for Create, Read, Update and Delete. For the Update part, you most definitely do not want to truncate the whole table and re-insert all the data every time (unless the specific use case demands that). You just want to update only the affected rows.

Comment: Could you tell me the reason why you suggested the 2nd one? i.e reactjs approach.
and regarding the CRUD operations, could you please elaborate on what you were saying.